# Handling touchesBegan in the main view - how to get ahold of the touched subview?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, hittest, touchesbegan

In an single view iPhone app I have the following structure: `scrollView -> contentView -> imageView` and underneath (at the main view) there are 7 draggable custom views - which can be dragged from/to the `contenView`.

Initially dragging was handled in the custom views (see [Tile.m@2eb672523a](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/2eb672523a9dcc313e6cf8f940bf42884fed6645/ScrollContent/ScrollContent/Tile.m)) and while this worked well it required sending notifications to the main view.

So I'm trying to move `touchesBegan` and friends to the main app view (see [ViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/ScrollContent/ScrollContent/ViewController.m)).

**My problem is:**

Initially I had this code in the `contentView` (see [GameBoard.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/ScrollContent/ScrollContent/GameBoard.m)) to enable subview dragging at the `scrollView`:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView* result = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    return result == self ? nil : result;
}
```

However when trying to drag a tile back from `contentView` to the main view (in the direction shown in the below screenshot) this wouldn't deliver `touchesBegan` to the main view.

[image: app screenshot]

So I have changed this method to return the main view instead of the tiles:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView* result = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    return result == self ? nil : self.window.rootViewController.view;
}
```

Now `touchesBegan` is called on the main view (as I can see in the debugger), but the `touches.view` is pointing to the main view too.

**My question is:**

How to find the touched tile in the new `touchesBegan` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I've solved my problem.

In [ViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/ScrollContent/ScrollContent/ViewController.m) I've added a `_draggedTile` ivar and set it in `touchesBegan` by using the following method to find the touched tile:

```
- (SmallTile*) findTileAtPoint:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    NSArray* children = [self.view.subviews arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:_contentView.subviews];

    for (UIView* child in children) {
        CGPoint localPoint = [child convertPoint:point fromView:self.view];

        if ([child isKindOfClass:[SmallTile class]] &&
            [child pointInside:localPoint withEvent:event]) {
            return (SmallTile*)child;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

And in `touchedMoved`, `touchesEnded`, `touchesCancelled` I just use that ivar (initially I was using the above `findTileAtPoint:withEvent:` method there as well, but sometimes the touch wouldn't be exactly over the dragged tile and the movement was jerky or cancelled).